# Webgl: MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS changes depending on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-browser, gpu, webgl

I am working on webgl code that has been working perfectly fine for me up until I ran it on chrome. I found the exact problem through debugging and found that a single parameter difference was causing the problem.

In chrome and node (gl is the webgl context):

```
console.log(gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)); // returns 64
```

In firefox:

```
console.log(gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS)); // returns 192
```

I think these numbers might be specific to your own devices GPU. Im not switching gpu's every time i change browsers. I'm not sure why this happens, but it happens in chrome and node, and it breaks my GPU heavy code. Is there any way to possibly unlock full access to the GPU capabilities?

A solution for nodejs would be the most appreciated as the browser limiting GPU use is understandable, but I still need to run heavy GPU code.

Answer (score 1):

There's not. `MAX_COMBINED_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` isn't something you should care for to begin with as it's not specific enough, it's either `MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS` or `MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`, depending on where you need those units.

Some vendors report high values but fallback to inefficient means to deal with high texture unit usage, while some backends (DirectX, OpenGL, OpenGL ES, Vulkan) have differing values due to driver capabilities.

I'll go on a limb here and claim that you don't really need all those texture units but instead need to not provide your data atomically to the gpu but instead pack it properly, which will not only increase your compatibility but also your performance.

Comment: I don't know much about using WebGL. If I had a better GPU, would it make the numbers higher?